# SQLKata Update Query Including FromRaw Statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlkata

I am trying to create an update query in SQLKata that includes a 'FromRaw' statement.   Below is a copy of my best attempt at what I am trying to accomplish.  I have to use a FromRaw statement because I am linking 2 tables on an evaluation.  Is there any way to accomplish this without having to resort to the Statement() function?

```
var query = db.Query(Table1)

                .FromRaw(" Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 " +
                " ON LEFT([Table1].[Company],5) = " +
                " LEFT([Table2].[Company],5)" )

                .Update(new { scrub = "match" });
```

Below is a copy of the error message: 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid table expression'

Comment: Are you using an old version of SqlKata? This worked for me using SqlServer. The only thing I can think of is to make sure you're using the SqlServerCompiler.

Comment: I am using cersion 1.1..7 of SqlKata.Execution.  And I am using SqlServerCompiler.  Can you post a snippet of the query that you created?

Comment: I've added my code below

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code works just fine for me:

```
var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
//var Table1 = "Table1";

var query = new Query(null)
        .FromRaw("Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 " +
        "ON LEFT([Table1].[Company],5) = " +
        "LEFT([Table2].[Company],5)")
        .AsUpdate(new { scrub = "match" });

var rawSql = compiler.Compile(query).RawSql;
```

With `rawSql` value being:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON LEFT([Table1].[Company],5) = LEFT([Table2].[Company],5) SET [scrub] = ?
```

The error message you're getting is only found in `Compiler.cs`, which is why I suggested that you check which compiler you're using.

Comment: I copied your code and it still throws the same error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid table expression'  After that I commented out the .AsUpdate and changed it to just a .Select() and that ran successfully with no errors.  And when I copied the sql statement into SSMS it executed with no errors.   To confirm, I am and have been using the SqlServer compiler.  Any ideas on what I could check next?

Comment: If you have your code on GitHub or something then I can take a look, but the other other thing I can think of would be your version of sqlkata is old.