# How can i make raw cross join with SqlKata library

Tags: c#, postgresql, sqlkata

I’m use PostgreSQL with C# with SqlKata library.
How can I make such query with SqlKata library?

```
select rt.id as report_template_id, 
       string_agg(rtb.code, ',' order by b.idx) as aggregated_code
from report_template rt
  cross join unnest(rt.template_blocks_id) with ordinality as b(template_id, idx)
  join report_template_block rtb on rtb.id = b.template_id
group by rt.id
order by rt.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FromRaw` to achieve that

```
var query = new Query().FromRaw("report_template rt cross join unnest(rt.template_blocks_id) with ordinality as b(template_id, idx)")
  .Join("report_template_block as rtb", "rtb.id", "b.template_id")
  .GroupBy("rt.id")
  .OrderBy("rt.id");
```

check the example on [SqlKata Playground](https://sqlkata.com/playground/oracle?code=var%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query().FromRaw(%22report_template%20rt%20cross%20join%20unnest(rt.template_blocks_id)%20with%20ordinality%20as%20b(template_id%2C%20idx)%22)%0A%20%20.Join(%22report_template_block%20as%20rtb%22%2C%20%22rtb.id%22%2C%20%22b.template_id%22)%0A%20%20.GroupBy(%22rt.id%22)%0A%20%20.OrderBy(%22rt.id%22)%3B)

Very similar to this one [SQLKata Update Query Including FromRaw Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146420/sqlkata-update-query-including-fromraw-statement)